# Ubuntu, how do you remove all Python 3 but not 2

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have recently get hold of a RackSpace Ubuntu server and it has pythons all over the place:

iPython in 3.5, Pandas in 3.4 &2.7, modules I need like pyodbc etc. are only in 2,7

Therefore, I am keen to clean up the box and, as a 2.7 users, keep everything in 2.7.

So the key question is, is there a way to remove both 3.4 and 3.5 efficiently at the same time while keeping Python 2.7?

Comment: Note that [pyodbc *does* work](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/blob/master/setup.py#L98) on Python 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I worked out at the end that you cannot uninstall 3.4 as it is default on Ubuntu.

All I did was simply remove `Jupyter` and then alias `python=python2.7` and install all packages on Python 2.7 again.

Arguably, I can install `virtualenv` but me and my colleagues are only using 2.7. I am just going to be lazy in this case :)

Comment: You may want to dig deeper. Ubuntu still defaults to Python 2.7, although they are moving towards Python 3: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3 This could indicate a different issue with your setup.

Answer (score 20):

Removing Python 3 was the worst thing I did since I recently moved to the world of Linux. It removed Firefox, my launcher and, as I read while trying to fix my problem, it may also remove your desktop and terminal! Finally fixed after a long daytime nightmare. Just don't remove Python 3. Keep it there!

If that happens to you, here is the fix:

https://askubuntu.com/q/384033/402539

https://askubuntu.com/q/810854/402539

Comment: I just did it, how to fix it?

Comment: @RohitNair Did you try the suggested fixes linked on my post (from askubuntu)? I tried them and they worked with me. If you don't have a terminal (most probably), then press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get a virtual console and get started

Comment: @RohitNair Try `apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: So, if a language version is removed, all hell breaks loose at the OS level? Not exactly an advertisement for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT:** As pointed out in recent comments, this solution may **BREAK** your system.

***You most likely don't want to remove python3.***

Please refer to the other answers for possible solutions.

*Outdated answer (not recommended)*

> sudo apt-get remove 'python3.*'

Comment: you mean `sudo apt-get remove python3*`

Comment: Great thanks! Just a follow up, will this remove all the folders/ modules for Python3 or will I have to remove them manually afterward?

Comment: It does not work unfortunately, I have got this error:    cloud-guest-utils : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 cloud-image-utils : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages

Comment: If we do above command it uninstall mysql, chrome and many more packages.

Comment: Actually this command worked for me but for my friend on 14.04 all of its packages got removed.

Comment: @DevendraBhat Maybe your friend didn't use the single quote around 'python3.*', thus selecting every packages with the alias *

Comment: Ubuntu depends on Python 3. Removing it will break many things.

Comment: This stupid command removed many core packages from my system, and left it in a broken state, please remove this reply.

Comment: DO NOT run this command !!! python3 is used in many system utils and applications. RUNNING this command will destroy your system.

Comment: I updated the answer to warn further readers against using this solution.

Comment: Why don't you remove this answer?

Comment: Can you remove this answer?

Comment: Better remove than warning

Comment: Please remove this answer.this will destroy your ubuntu system..

Comment: took me 3 hrs to recover my system back ,please delete this comment .

Answer (score 7):

First of all, don't try the following command as suggested by Germain above.

```
   `sudo apt-get remove 'python3.*'`
```

In Ubuntu, many software depends upon Python3 so if you will execute this command it will remove all of them as it happened with me. I found following answer useful to recover it.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/810854/i-deleted-package-python3-on-ubuntu-and-i-have-lost-dashboard-terminal-and-un

**If you want to use different python versions for different projects then create virtual environments it will be very useful. refer to the following link to create virtual environments.**

*Creating Virtual Environment also helps in using Tensorflow and Keras in Jupyter Notebook.*

https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/setup-python-virtual-environment-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

neither try any above ways nor `sudo apt autoremove python3` because it will remove all gnome based applications from your system including gnome-terminal. **In case if you have done that mistake and left with kernal only than try`sudo apt install gnome` on kernal.**

try to change your default python version instead removing it. you can do this through **bashrc file** or **export path** command.

Answer (score -3):

Its simple
just try:
sudo apt-get remove python3.7 or the versions that you want to remove